# What is the difference between "object" and "objective"?

Tags: difference, vocabulary

Who knows exactly the difference between *objective* and *object*?

For instance:

> The government whose object/objective is the good of people...

Answer (score 1):

In a broader sense, an **object** is a visible entity. But both those words, **object** and **objective** have a common meaning referring to:

> The goal intended to be attained (and which is believed to be attainable)

Various other words which can be used are *aim* and *target*. Therefore, all the following have the same meaning:

> - The government whose **objective** is the good of people.
> - The government whose **object** is the good of people.
> - The government whose **aim** is the good of people.
> - The government whose **target** is the good of people.

Comment: What about *goal*?

Comment: @Em1 Yeah, that too!

Comment: I think I agree that "object" and "objective" are both good. However, I somehow feel that "The government whose object is the good of people" sounds better. Perhaps it's because "object" sounds a bit more poetic and archaic, and "the good of people" is abstract enough.

Comment: I do not think so. In my opinion, they are never synonym, above all, as such my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically, *object* would refer to the recipient of an action and an objective may be a complement of the object.

> The electorate elected him president.

Answer (score 0):

There are other words as well like " select" which is different from "selective"- select means of special class / carefully chosen as being the best or most suitable. Similarly removal of suffix "-ive"
 makes something special like Object stands for not purpose but ultimate purpose

Comment: Kindly add details (and it would be best to add references as well).

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's very slight in the usage,  One of Purpose vs a goal.

The object of the government - the Purpose of government
The objective of the government - the goal of the government

In the one since it is their reason for being, in the other it is potentially one of many desired end states, or temporary goals along a path to a particular end state.

Also I would suggest that form or use of "The object of the government.." is becoming antiquated or archaic.